# Extracting Metadata From a video File

Tags: android

I have a Video File, I have to extract metadata from this, it contains some metadata
on its Network byte. actually in duration of video, we have to find out the offset value(8 bytes), this contains metadata in xml form.
I am unable to find out how to do this task.
can anyone help me??
Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide more animation. How is this related to Android?

Comment: i have to do this task in android.